# counting string-indexed tables in lua

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua

I am trying to count elements in a table that has some elements indexed with strings. When I try to use the # operator, it just ignores string indexed ones. example:

```
local myTab = {1,2,3}
print(#myTab)
```

will return 3

```
local myTab = {}
myTab["hello"] = 100
print(#myTab)
```

will return 0
mixing them, I tried

```
local myTab = {1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7}
print(#myTab)
myTab["test"] = try
print(#myTab)
```

returned 7 and then 3, that is right because I read somewhere that the # operator stops when it finds a nil value (but then why the first print printed 7?)

last, I tried

```
local myT = {123,456,789}
myT["test"] = 10
print(#myT)
```

printing 3, not 4

Why?

Comment: Why do you need to count elements in a table? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "the # operator stops when it finds a nil value" is not correct. The [Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6) explains it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is simple, from [the length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7):

> Unless a `__len` metamethod is given, the length of a table `t` is only defined if the table is a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to `{1..n}` for some non-negative integer `n`. In that case, `n` is its length.

In your example:

```
local myTab = {1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7}
```

`#mytab` is undefined because `myTab` isn't a sequence, with or without `myTab["test"] = try`.

```
local myT = {123,456,789}
```

`myT` is a sequence, and the length is `3`, with or without `myT["test"] = 10`

Comment: thanks, but then what is the right way to count them?

Comment: @FedericoFallico: Manually, by iterating over them all.