# lua string-indexed table and unpack

Tags: lua

I have a table in lua populated by items with string index. It is known, unfortunately, that lua doesn't handle this in a perfect (headache-free) way because the `#` operator and `table.unpack()` won't work

```
t = {}
t['b'] = 2
t['a'] = 1

print("l:", #t)
print("t:", table.unpack(t))
```

returns:

```
l:  0
t:
```

There are solution to count the items (i.e: [counting string-indexed tables in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983125/counting-string-indexed-tables-in-lua)) but i wasn't able to find a replacement for the `table.unpack()` someone can give an hand?

The desired output is: `2 1` (in the same order as I added them)

Comment: How would your `unpack` work? how is the order defined for the values to be unpacked? is it just the value or does it unpack them to something like an array structured like `{{key="a", value =1}, {key="b", value =2}}`. these questions are why you wont see a 1 size fits all solution, as how you want unpack to behave is likely specific to you structure

Comment: The order is not important right now, I may sort them before of after. Ideally I would love to unpack them in the same order they have been added into the table but this is not mandatory

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `print("t:", table.unpack(t))` must give out? `print("t:", table.unpack({'a','b','c'}))` gives `t: a b c`

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @aster94: You've said what the desired output is, but not *why* that is the desired output. That is, do you desire that output because you "inserted" the keys in that order? Because that information doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua tables store non-array elements in an arbitrary order. And unpacking is worthless without some control over the order of the generated elements. So it's not possible to usefully unpack the non-array portion of a table.

Now, you can still do it; you just won't have any kind of control over the order. So it's not clear what the point would be, but the code would look like this:

```
function unpack_unordered_recursive(tbl, key)
  local new_key, value = next(tbl, key)
  if new_key == nil then return end

  return value, unpack_unordered_recursive(tbl, new_key)
end

function unpack_unordered(tbl)
  local key, value = next(tbl)
  if key == nil then return end

  return value, unpack_unordered_recursive(tbl, key)
end
```

However, if you have an array table that contains the list of keys to extract and the order to extract them in, then you can write an unpack function that uses such a table:

```
function unpack_indices(tbl, indices, curr_ix)
  if curr_ix == nil then
    return unpack_indices(tbl, indices, 1)
  end

  if curr_ix > #indices then
    return
  end

  --Recursive call
  return tbl[indices[curr_ix]], unpack_indices(tbl, indices, curr_ix + 1)
end

print("t:", unpack_indices(t, {"b", "a"}))
```

Comment: the `unpack_indices` version is just perfect, thanks